# How does the SQL function COALESCE() work?

Tags: sql

The SQL COALESCE() function can be described in a single sentence: COALESCE returns the first non-NULL value passed for each row. Please rephrase this sentence in a simple, logical manner with an example.

```
-- assume the a.id column contains the one and only NULL value in a large table
SELECT COALESCE(a.id, a.id) AS modified_id
FROM accounts a
```

This has the surprising result of actually creating a value in the new column modified_id! If the first argument in the function is NULL, how can the second argument (the value to replace the NULL in the first argument) produce anything in the resulting modified_id? We know the value in second argument must be NULL as it is literally the first argument.

Edit:

The following code produces the result in [2018-08-05_20-39-19.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtIvW.jpg)

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts a
LEFT JOIN orders o
ON a.id = o.account_id
WHERE o.total IS NULL;
```

The following code produces the result in [2018-08-05_20-43-14.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKGYb.jpg)

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(a.id, a.id) AS filled_id,
    a.name, a.website, a.lat, a.long, a.primary_poc, a.sales_rep_id, o.*
FROM accounts a
LEFT JOIN orders o
ON a.id = o.account_id
WHERE o.total IS NULL;
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: If a.id is null, COALESCE(a.id, a.id) is null.

Comment: @qxg yes, that was my thinking as well, however it is simply not the case. With a.id null, this code still returns a value to modified_id. That is why I posted the question.

Comment: The problem should not be COALESCE, but somewhere else in you script. Can you create a minimal repro, like `SELECT COALESCE(a.id, a.id) AS modified_id FROM accounts a where a.id IS NULL`.

Comment: Which sql engine are you using? One of the questions I have is whether this is a peculiar bug in the program. COALESCE(NULL,NULL) should return NULL.

Comment: @qxg edited my question with more details, please take a look.

Comment: @DrewSommer, can you make sure two query return the same row? Is there NULL account_id in orders table?

Comment: @qxg yes, the two queries return the same row. There is only one row with any null values, within this row both a.id and o.account_id are null. This is the row under discussion, that is being returned by both queries.

Comment: Here is the problem: NULL = NULL returns false. Actually Null = AnyValue returns false. So I think order table is totally unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a typo, or some other simple reason.

It is very easy to verify, just return both `a.id` and `COALESCE(a.id, a.id)` in the same query together. Make sure to use aliases, so that you know that you are looking at `a.id` and not `id` from some other table.

```
SELECT
    a.id AS a_id,
    COALESCE(a.id, a.id) AS filled_id,
    a.name, a.website, a.lat, a.long, a.primary_poc, a.sales_rep_id, o.*
FROM accounts a
LEFT JOIN orders o
ON a.id = o.account_id
WHERE o.total IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you. Both the orders table and the accounts table had a column named id. In fact, the a.id was not null on this row, but the o.id was ... causing confusion. I appreciate everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

For this example you've provided, if a.id is null of course the second a.id will be null.

COALESCE is helpful with left joins for e.g

```
select coalesce(DE.user_id, KBU.user_id, OUD.user_id) as User_ID          
        LEFT JOIN dm.EDW.DIM_Employee DE
            ON de.user_id = RIGHT(SubQuery.[UserID], LEN(SubQuery.[UserID]) - 5)
            AND de.dss_current_flag = 'Y'
            AND de.Dss_Deleted_Flag = 'N'

        -- Some of the users are missing from our Dim Table so need to use other sources
        LEFT JOIN tts..load_KBNetwork_Users KBU
            ON KBU.UID = RIGHT(SubQuery.[UserID], LEN(SubQuery.[UserID]) - 5)

        LEFT JOIN dm.dbo.organisationunitdimension OUD
            ON oud.OrgUnitLevel5SourceId = RIGHT(SubQuery.[UserID], LEN(SubQuery.[UserID]) - 5)
            AND oud.dss_current_flag = 'Y'
```

if `DE` is null then I can get the first null value from the next two (if possible)

Comment: please see my edited question, I agree with your statements however the result is as described ... not null, although both input arguments are certainly null.

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE(First_Column_Value, Second_Column_Value, Third_Column_Value) as Derived_Column_Name Explanation: We can use multiple column_names in COALESCE and which ever column has as value that will be treated as the first value and it will be captured in the derived_column_name. If the values in the First_Column_Value is present, display that else check for the value in the Second_Column_Value and if its present display that, if not then check Third_Column_Value and display that.

Example:
COALESCE(ea.AdmissionDate,ta.AdmissionDate) as Patient_Admission_Date
Here 'ea' and 'ta' are two different tables or they could be same table with two different aliases in case of a self join.

Likewise,
COALESCE() can be used for multiple columns.
COALESCE(ea.Admission_ID,ta.Transfer_ID, ca.Exit_ID) as Patient_Admission_Date

Similarly,
COALESCE() can be used with another inbuilt function, such as DATEADD().

COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DD,ca.AdmissionDate,ca.DischargeDate), DATEDIFF(DD,ta.AdmissionDate,ta.DischargeDate)) AS Difference_Of_Days

Needless to say that COALESCE() is usually written in your select statement as it can be used for a derived_column,Nonetheless, it can also be used in the join clause.

For instance,
Select * from Employees ea
left join Sales_DB..Sales_Pipeline p on COALESCE(ea.SRN, ta.SRN) = p.SRN

where, ea is an alias for Employees table, left joined to a table called Sales_Pipeline aliased as p on the COALESCE(either of the two column values)
SRN means sales_record_number.

Comment: Seems like you've just looked at the question title and answered that.  If you'd had examined the question and all of it's responses then this answer should not have even been posted.